# How to use API methods for angular matInput

Tags: angular, typescript

I want to learn how to use matInput methods mentioned in angular documentation [official documentation](https://material.angular.io/components/input/api) , I tried using 'isFocused' but it is not working. I want to print to console if input element is focused.

Here is what I tried

**app.component.html**

```
<form class="example-form">
  <mat-form-field class="example-full-width">
    <mat-label>Favorite food</mat-label>
    <input matInput placeholder="Ex. Pizza" value="Sushi" (isFocused)="onFocus($event)" >
  </mat-form-field>
</form>
```

**app.component.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

/**
 * @title Basic Inputs
 */
@Component({
  selector: 'app.component',
  styleUrls: ['app.component.css'],
  templateUrl: 'app.component.html'
})
export class AppComponent {
  onFocus($event: any) {
    console.log($event.target.value); --> nothing is printed
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can listen on `focus` or `focusin` element event

```
<input matInput placeholder="Ex. Pizza" value="Sushi" (focusin)="onFocus($event)" >
```